# How to place and access an object of type class within a queue

Tags: c#, class, object, queue

So basically I have a Job class

```
public class Job
{
   private string id;               
   private int numBytes;           
   private int requiredTime; 
}
```

within my main i receive values and create the job

```
var aJob = new Job();
Queue jobQueue = new Queue();
```

I want to be able to take the job info out of the queue as a job again

```
Job test = new Job();           
test = (Job)jobQueue.Peek();
```

however when I print it out I recieve "Job"

```
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

I've also recieved a compiler error when I use:

```
test = jobQueue.Peek();
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Job'. An explicit conversion exists     
(are you missing a cast?)
```

basically the goal here is to store jobs in a queue and access the job's individual properties.

much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to use a [`Queue<Job>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx). The non-generic version is for old versions of .Net Framework which you shouldn't use for new code any more.

Second, you can't print the properties (they are not called attributes) of a custom class just by calling `Console.WriteLine()`. You'll need to print them individually, like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Id = {0}", test.id);
Console.WriteLine("numBytes = {0}", test.numBytes);
Console.WriteLine("requiredTime = {0}", test.requiredTime);
```

Or override the `ToString()` method like described by the other answer.

Comment: Be careful with your wording.  You can use the non generic `Queue` class.  It's just not as elegant because you'll need a cast.

Comment: I have changed it to `Queue<Job> jobQueue = new Queue<Job>();` and I receive the error _"The non-generic type 'System.Collections.Queue' cannot be used with type arguments._

Comment: @steaks That's why I said "shouldn't use for new code" rather than "can't use".

Comment: @ChanceSQ `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: "first, you'll need to use a `Queue<Job>`" implies that the OP needs to use a `Queue<Job>`.  Does it not?

Comment: @steaks Sure. I changed it to "you'll want to use".

Comment: @ChanceSQ Do you have `using Queue = System.Collections.Queue;` anywhere in your code? Otherwise it shouldn't resolve to the non-generic type automatically.

Comment: that is nowhere in my code, I realize this should work and I've restarted the program and my computer and nothing has changed this issue

Comment: still doesn't work on mine.. very odd, I'll try re-installing visual studio, thanks for your help however!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the generic queue instead:

```
Queue<Job> jobQueue = new Queue<Job>();
```

You see "Job" printed because you did not override `ToString()`.

Comment: for some reason I am unable to do `Queue<Job> jobQueue = new Queue<Job>();` I receive the error _"The non-generic type 'System.Collections.Queue' cannot be used with type arguments."_

here is all the code for this http://collabedit.com/nfjeh

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) instead of a `Queue`.

Then, override the `ToString()` method of your `Job` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return string.Format("id: {0}, numBytes: {1}, requiredTime: {2}", id, numBytes, requiredTime);
}
```

And then, after taking the job info from the queue, use the `ToString()` method to print out the information:

```
Job test = new Job();           
test = jobQueue.Peek(); // casting isn't longer necessary, because you use a Queue<T>
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
```